# How to mimic the stock Calendar app on watchOS?

Tags: swift, tableview, watchos-2, watchos-3

The stock calendar app on the Apple Watch has some UI elemnts I would be interested in implementing in my app. It shows each event in its own view and when scrolling up (with touch or the crown) the view is animated up and the next event is visible below.
Is this a default implementation or is it a modification of the WKInterfaceTable?

[image]

Thanks!

**EDIT**

After some testing it looks like they use a WKInterfacePicker with a style of 'Stack'. However, from what I understand only images can displayed in the WKPickerItem in this mode. Is that correct?